# htaccess example.com/page.php?cat=berlin&page=2 to example.com/berlin/2

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've searched all over the web but have not been able to find answers, so i hope you can help me.

I try to rewrite both the page and the category in my Htaccess as follows: example.com/page.php?cat=berlin&page=2 to example.com/berlin/2. Category can be different like Stockholm, Oslo, Copenhagen ...

Is there anybody inside that can show me how to do it?
Or refer to a place where they show it correctly.
I have try to use %1 but it did not work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /book.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: "Did not work" is never a sufficient problem description. Albeit you did seemingly look somthing up at least, still wondering why there's no attempt to even adapt e.g. `book.php` to `page.php`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use back-references and multiple capture groups to accomplish this. So something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/page.php\?cat=([a-z]+)&page=([0-9]+)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

This is making several assumptions, including that `cat` is always alpha characters and `page` is always numeric. Also see the apache documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html), specifically the section on Regex Back-Reference Availability.

Also, `%1` would match a capture group in a preceding `RewriteCond` not the current `RewriteRule` which uses the `$1` notation.